# The limitation of partition table updates in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

The [Quotas & Limits](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas?hl=en#partition) document says that "partition table updates" has the two below limitations.

- Daily limit: 2,000 partition updates per table, per day
- Rate limit: 50 partition updates every 10 seconds

My question is whether these limitations are applied to a partitoin table or ones in the dataset.

For example, is it possible to have thousands day-partitioned tables and perform streaming insert to each table everyday?

Comment: Not sure what is your question or issue. Regarding the updates, those quotas applies for each table, as stated in the docs. But as you asked about streaming, those quotas have nothing to do with streaming (this is not an update operation but rather a [Tabledata.insertAll](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tabledata/insertAll) operation). Streaming follows [these](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas?hl=en#streaminginserts) quotas.

Comment: I mean, I would like to confirm the daily and rate limit are applied for update counts per table, not sum of update counts of all tables in dataset or project. It should be 'per table' as you mentioned though the rate limit clearly says 'per table'. Thank you.